# How to save dataframes with changing names in a for loop in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I am doing some data analysis where I have my datasets in a folder and I use a for loop to go through all the datasets and (1) Plot a graph (2) Calculate some values from the graph and store them in a dataframe which is then appended to a list. The idea is to have graphs for each dataset and also a list having this summary dataframe for each dataset for analysis later.

With every dataset the for loop iterates through I have a variable specifying the current dataset in the loop. This variable is used to label and save the graph and to label and append the dataframe to a list. I am able to do the graph bit alright but I am not able to add the dataframe to the list in the for loop. My code is as follows:

```
# Create empty list for adding things to from each loop
  parameters <- list()

# Begin the loop
  for (file in filesVector) {
 
# Extract keywords from name of file to be used later
  splitname <- strsplit(file, '4-')
  splitname <- unlist(splitname)
  secondhalf <- splitname[2]
  splitsecondhalf <- strsplit(secondhalf, '\\.')
  splitsecondhalf <- unlist(splitsecondhalf)
  title <- splitsecondhalf[1]
  
# Extract values as a dataframe and assign to varying name    
  assign(paste(title, 'blanks', sep= '-'),data_drc_merge[data_drc_merge$ID == 
  "B", ])

# Add to list
  parameters <- c(parameters, paste(title, 'blanks', sep= '-'))
```

But when I try assigning it to a dataframe I get the current value of the variable added there instead

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Could you use `[[` and `paste0` to paste the name of the data.frame you want to add to your list:

```
list_of_df = list()
for(i in files){
# do analysis...
list_of_df[[paste0(name_, i)]] = current_df

}
```